# Squares related to circles

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

Fibonacci numbers, circles, squares; everything is connected in the digital world.
Can you make two squares from a circle? Seven decimals should be accurate enough.

Which two numbers am I seeking?

I already accepted an answer, but to be more clear:
I want to see a Fibonacci number > 10 in the answer. After all, who associates e.g. 2 with Fibonacci at first sight.
Mentioning decimals is to make it easier, since it won't work with less, and it hints to the most doubtful connection in the puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in Gareth's attempt, the goal is to

> use the digits of 3.1415926 to make squares.
>  The squares we want are 1156 (34^2) and 3249 (57^2).

Comment: Fibonacci was there to filter out solutions like 11, 186, and as a hint that I wanted the roots, but squares is good enough (Though in hindsight I did not check if duplicate solutions with 1,2,or 3. exist)

Answer (score 2):

This question seems a bit "guess what I happened to be thinking of"-y, but: If you consider "a circle"

> to mean $\pi$ (which is e.g. the area of a unit circle)

then those "seven decimals"

> get us 3.1415926

in which

> 4 and 9 are both squares.

I'm not sure whether

> the fact that 3, 1, 5, 2 are all Fibonacci numbers is supposed to be significant, given that the question mentions Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: almost there, you are supposed to use all digits somehow